# Why does it say I'm missing some dll's when they are actually there?

Tags: dll, clarion

So I'm working in Clarion 6 and the problem is when I make an application and try to make and run it says it's missing some dll's. Couse Clarion 6 doesn't support 64 bit system's im working in a virtual machine(Windows xp) run by Oracle VM virtual box. I also noticed that when I build the application and go to the folder of the application I can put the missing dll's from the Clarion 6 installation folder and then run it normaly. But still it isn't the way the application is meant to be started.

Comment: in the references have you set Copy Local = True ?

Comment: How your question is related to tagged `c#`? Please don't tag languages not involved.

Comment: Sry I didn't know I have put c# into tags.. My mistake sorry...

simon1230756 care to explain it better to me plz... I didn't do something like that

Answer (score 1):

Clarion6 relies on the path to point to the location of dependant DLLs during development.

Usually, as a minimum, you would expect to see this in the PATH environment variable:

`c:\clarion6\bin;c:\clarion6\3rdparty\bin;`

Of course when you distribute your application you will need to determine which DLLs are needed and ship then with your application.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution to this problem. If you are using a win xp virtual machine to run your Clarion 6 you need to copy all dll's from the bin folder from clarion to your windows folder

Comment: Whilst this would work it is not a particularly great idea. You would be much better off telling windows where to find those files by altering the PATH environment variable as described in my answer.